# Variable substitution in tcl

Tags: object, tcl, parameter-passing

I'm running an incarnation of tcl 8.5 that has been embedded into another system.
That system will accept and correctly execute a command such as:

```
uniformDist  minAndMax  {1 10}
```

where uniformDist is some object to which I do not have internal visibility.

I want to be able to say something like:

```
set M 1000
uniformDist  minAndMax  {1 M}
```

but this does not work.
Nor does
    set M 1000
    uniformDist  minAndMax  {1 $M}

I tried:

```
u minAndMax {1 [eval $M]}
```

and

```
u minAndMax {1 [eval M]}
```

Neither of those works.

The error message is:

> expected a real value: unable to convert from: "$M"Error: expected
>   fewer arguments  [Error while parsing pair]

or

> expected a real value: unable to convert from: "[eval"Error: expected
>   fewer arguments  [Error while parsing pair]

What is the right way that tcl does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable substitution is expressed using `$` and the variable's name (such as `$M` or `${M}`).

This doesn't work:

```
uniformDist  minAndMax  {1 $M}
```

because the braces prevent substitution: `$M` is just the (sub)string 'dollar, upper case m'.

**This works:**

```
uniformDist  minAndMax  [list 1 $M]
```

because the arguments to list will be evaluated before the list `{1 1000}` is returned and passed to `uniformDist`.

The form `"1 $M"` would work too, and the command substitution `[set M]` can be used instead of the variable substitution above.

Documentation:
[Summary of Tcl language syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Comment: There's also using `"1 $M"` and `[subst {1 $M}]`, but the `list` command has fewest surprises with complex substituands.